# How-to deploy to application server web project with non-webproject structure (within Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

Basically what I want is to deploy from Eclipse web project to application server (WebLogic). The problem is that project source files are structured differently than what application server expects (i.e. there is no WEB-INF containing deployment descriptor). As a results when I try to deploy my project to app server it is not recognized as deployable app. Is there a smart and elegant way how-to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i will answer my question myself. Basically this situation can be solved by creating a new dynamic web project with the required structure and then using Linked folder functionality of eclipse.